# return all columns with values that contain string pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below.  I would like to find all columns in the dataframe that contain a string ‘abc’ and return a list of those fields like the example below.  If I was looking for the rows I would use isin, but I'm not sure how to get the columns.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Example:

```
Print df

Field1  Field2  Field3
f_abc   23      dog
Df3     bb      ju


Return 

Field1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this with list comprehension on `df.columns`.

First let's create an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"], data=[['abc']*3]*3)
df['D'] = 'ab'
```

results in:

```
     A   B   C  D
0   abc abc abc ab
1   abc abc abc ab
2   abc abc abc ab
```

Now let's print only the columns that contain 'abc':

```
print([col for col in df.columns if df[col].str.contains("abc").any()])
```

['A', 'B', 'C']

Comment: similar to dictionaries, you can do `col for col in df`, but good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make use of pandas `pd.Series.isin` which returns a boolean series.

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data={'Field1':['f_abc', 21], 'Field2':[23, 'bb'], 'Field3':['dog', 'ju']}, columns=['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3'])

print([i for i in mydf if mydf[i].isin(['f_abc']).any()])
```

(don't yet have the reputation to have added this as a comment)