# Is there a python way to merge multiple cells with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, merge

I needed to search multiple cells for a specific value and when it is found it should be returned in new column.

I got an answer here; [Python: find string in multiple columns and return it in new column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59879678/3105140) yet this line below return the first value found

```
df['b'] = (df[cols].where(df[cols].stack().str.contains('b')
         .unstack(fill_value=False)).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1])
```

where cols

```
df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']]
```

I tried the other answers and they all gave me  error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Do any one have an idea how can I get all the matching values in one cell.

the data set

```
ID   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
1    jack  a/h   t/m   w/n   y/h    56
2    sam   z/n   b/w   null  b/n   93
3    john  b/i   y/d   b/d   null   33
```

The code I'm using now :

```
df['b'] = (df[cols].where(df[cols].stack().str.contains('b')
         .unstack(fill_value=False)).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1])
```

And here the output I am getting now

```
ID   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  b
1    jack  a/h   t/m   w/n   y/h    56   -
2    sam   z/n   b/w   null  b/n   93   b/w
3    john  b/i   y/d   b/d   null   33   b/i
```

And actually I want the output to look like the data-frame below

```
ID   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5     b 
1    jack  a/h   t/m   w/n   y/h    56    null
2    sam   z/n   b/w   null  b/n    93   b/w - b/n
3    john  b/i   y/d   b/d   null   33   b/i - b/d
```

Comment: please provide input and expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter dataframe containing columns `col1-col4` and use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then using [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) filter the stacked dataframe finally use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on `level=0` and aggregate using `join`:

```
s = df.filter(regex=r'col[1-4]').stack()
s = s[s.str.contains('b')].groupby(level=0).agg(' - '.join)
df['b'] = s
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   ID  col0 col1 col2 col3 col4  col5          b
0   1  jack  a/h  t/m  w/n  y/h    56        NaN
1   2   sam  z/n  b/w  NaN  b/n    93  b/w - b/n
2   3  john  b/i  y/d  b/d  NaN    33  b/i - b/d
```

Comment: Hi @Shubham this code miss half of the records The current result is 
`   ID  col0 col1 col2 col3 col4  col5          b
0   1  jack  a/h  t/m  w/n  y/h    56        NaN
1   2   sam  z/n  b/w  NaN  b/n    93  b/w - b/n
2   3  john  b/i  y/d  b/d  NaN    33  NaN`

Comment: @SMO Can you please elaborate more, exactly what problem you are facing?

Comment: So the result I am getting now is missing info in the new column. The result now is showing empty cell in columns: b , row: 2.  That means even if there is b the in col1-4 we do not always get it at the new column "b"

Comment: Are you specifically talking about the example you have provided in the question, or some other dataset? Because I've just checked the code is producing proper results on the example you provided.

Comment: My original df has more than 35 columns to be searched for the key word. and when i tried the code on it it kept missing some columns although every thing seems identical (spelling and space) Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: yes I did  this is my line  `df.filter(regex=r'Operation/Summary/[0-35]')` 0-35 is within the name of the operation not the index could that be the problem

Comment: can you elaborate, I could not understand this

Comment: @SMO We have to use a more advance regex pattern to match the desired columns, so use `df.filter(regex=r'Operation/Summary/(?:[0-9]|[0-2][0-9]?|3[0-5])$')` instead.

Comment: It worked ! thanks do you have and documentation for you approach or a link to explain it. I need to understand how it worked and what if the columns number changed how I can change. **Thanks again**

Comment: @SMO Its just a regex pattern, in case you need to change your columns in future you have to update the regex pattern, here is [the link which explains the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/h8FKmO/1) that i've used here, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with `melt`:

```
t = df.melt(id_vars="ID", value_vars = ["col0", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], var_name=[]).dropna()

t = t[t.value.str.contains("b")].groupby("ID")["value"].apply(lambda x: " - ".join(x))

res = pd.concat([df, t], axis=1).rename(columns={"value":"b"})
```

The output is:

```
    ID  col0 col1 col2 col3 col4  col5          b
0  1.0  jack  a/h  t/m  w/n  y/h  56.0        NaN
1  2.0   sam  z/n  b/w  NaN  b/n  93.0        NaN
2  3.0  john  b/i  y/d  b/d  NaN  33.0  b/w - b/n
3  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  b/i - b/d
```